# Xamarin Shell Raise Ambiguous Routes matched Exception

Tags: forms, shell, xamarin, routes

In Xamari.Forms, I use the following route declaration in *AppShell.xaml* :

```
 <FlyoutItem Title = "Toolbox"
             FlyoutDisplayOptions="AsMultipleItems"
             Route="Main">

      <ShellContent Title = "Toolbox"
                    ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate Views:Toolbox}"
                    Route="Toolbox"/>

 </FlyoutItem>

 <ShellContent Title = "Parameters"
               ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate Views:Parameters}"
               Route="Parameters"/>
```

In the *AppShell.xaml.cs*, I add programatically a contextual page navigation for the *Toolbox* page:

```
public AppShell ()
{
    InitializeComponent ();

    Routing.RegisterRoute("Toolbox/TBOuvriers", typeof(TBOuvriers));

    BindingContext = this;
}
```

When I try to display the contextual page navigation from the Toolbox Page:
*await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("//Main/Toolbox/TBOuvriers");*

I get this Exception :

> System.ArgumentException: Ambiguous routes matched for: //Main/Toolbox/TBOuvriers matches found:
>   //Main/Toolbox/TBOuvriers/TBOuvriers,
>   //Main/IMPL_Toolbox/Toolbox/TBOuvriers
>   Parameter name: uri

Just before the call, I can see those values for the Shell variables : 
*Shell.Current.CurrentItem :  "Title = Toolbox, Route = Main"

Shell.Current.CurrentState.Location : "{//Main/Toolbox}"*

**Which seem to be the expected one's.**

If I try to display the page with this call: 
*await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("TBOuvriers");*
I also get an Exception :  System.Exception: Timeout exceeded getting exception details

So, What's the problem ?
Where does those routes come from ?!?
Why is the Toolbox page 2 times registered ?

All ideas are welcome !

Best regards

Comment: Looking further in the articles on the web, I see that peoples mainly declare new pages - likes Contextual pages - as global when they doesn't appear in the fyout menu. It works for me if I do so. Is there a problem to declare them like in the xamarin shell doc as child of an existing page (like in my topic) ?

Comment: Same observation :  In the Xanimals demo projet, they do `"Routing.RegisterRoute("monkeydetails", typeof(MonkeyDetailPage));"` instead of `"Routing.RegisterRoute("monkey/details", typeof(MonkeyDetailPage));"` Why ?It should be easier to call *"await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("details");"* from each animal page instead of *"await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"{state.Location}/{destinationRoute}?name={animalName}");"*

Comment: ,you can try this way in your project, any issue here?

Comment: I do the same than in XAnimals. All my stand alone pages are registered in the root. But I can't succeed to apply way they propose in the official documentation. So, works for me but not the best way, maybe.

Comment: If you have better way to solved this issue, please sharing here, thanks.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

For anyone that will face this issue, and have this error message too;

> System.ArgumentException: 'Ambiguous routes matched for: ...'

This occures when you register your routes in XAML (in the appshell file) and you also try registering your routes in code behind in C#.
Only register your routes once using either XAML or C# not both.

Comment: I want to add that if it is registered in both places and I do await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("..");, the app crashes with a System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
This also fixed it.

Comment: What does this look like practically though. I have a set of flyout items defined in the XAML but I have defined the routes in the AppShell code behind. Do I need to define the Flyout items in the code behind? If have tried registering the routes in XAML only but that prevents me from using relative routes.

Comment: Thanks Damien, spend few hours thinking what the heck I'm doing wrong lol

Answer (score 1):

if you must have 2 registration for whatever reason try:

```
<Tab Title="Groups">    
    <ShellContent Route="HomeTab"  ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:Home}" />
</Tab>
```

Then in code

```
 Routing.RegisterRoute("Home", typeof(Home)))
```

Depending on your navigation you would want to try:

```
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("//HomeTab", true);
```

or

```
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("//Home", true);
```

PS I hate AppShell navigation